# Should I exercise my stock options (NSO's) before or after moving from Canada to U.S.?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, canada, employee-stock-options

I'm planning on changing my residency in a coming year from Canada to U.S. (Canadian citizen). I have NSO's of a private US corporation and have the option to exercise my vested options. I'm going to a state with low state income tax, but I'm not sure what the better strategy would be for these options.

Comment: How long do you plan to reside in the US? Do you plan to exercise the options before your return? Do you plan to retire there? Do you have any amounts in tax-advantaged accounts in Canada (TFSA, RRSP, RESP)?

Comment: I'm planning on moving for a longer time period (>5 years, if all goes well longer.) Yes I would be exercising before returning to Canada. My partner and I both have TFSAs

Comment: Okay there are many different issues at play here - highly advise you consider looking into an experienced dual Canadian / US tax accounting firm for at least the 1st year after you move. Issues at play: Departure tax on leaving Canada (https://www.cpacanada.ca/en/news/canada/2021-05-31-departure-tax), issue of determining date of residency, potential 1st year filing issues, and ongoing FATCA filings for TFSA's held in Canada [these are technically 'Trusts' and at least when I was practicing, they were a major headache for American taxpayers]. Tax of work-based options can also be complex.

Comment: I would say a rule of thumb might be in the range of - if you have > $50k combined investments, paying $1k-5k for 1st year filing of all relevant returns in a way that you understand for future self-filings, is almost certainly worth it. Done incorrectly, you could face either filing penalties or overpayment of tax that will be difficult to claw back.

Comment: A complete answer to your question might require complete analysis of all your income and investments, and would be well outside the scope of what an answer on this site could provide [I may be a bit cautious here, and someone might come along and say the question has minimal grey area and is thus answerable without numbers, so won't vote to close]. Good luck, I know this situation can be a real pain!